# MySQL - Give access to all users on a database

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

I've created a database with tables and functions I want every users to have access. Then I've granted all privileges to all users using this command:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,REFERENCES,INDEX,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,LOCK TABLES,EXECUTE ON  `dbname`.* TO ''@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I have access to the tables with other users, but when I execute a function I get this error:

```
execute command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' for routine 'dbname.functionname'
```

The function works fine with the root user who has his own privileges.

How can I get my function to be executed by all users?

Comment: When you try to run the function, are you connecting to 'localhost' (and not some other hostname that equates to the same machine)?

Comment: You must either grant permissions explicitly for each user, or allow connections by the anonymous user, grant permissions to '', as you have done, and then connect as the anonymous user: - see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html